# Saiku Analytics vs. Pivot4J

Tags: analytics, pentaho, olap-cube, saiku

I installed both the Saiku Analytics and the Pivot4J plugins on a Pentaho CE for a demo. From a high-level view, they both seem to be exactly the same, albeit Saiku seems to be performing a bit quicker. Can someone who is well acquainted with both please tell me the differences between the two and what factors I should take into consideration in selecting one over the other for Mondrain Cube analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, Saiku seems a better experience, also it's supported by other plugins like IvyDD.

A deeper analysis was made by the developer of JPivot on this awnser:

> Compared to Saiku, I think each project has its own advantage in
>   different scenarios.
>
> Saiku has a much lightweight architecture on the client side than our
>   sample application and the plugin, so it can be deployed and embedded
>   virtually anywhere.
>
> While it's not much difficult to create a full REST style analytic
>   application with Pivot4J, our current sample and plugin applications
>   require at least a Servlet container to run and are more difficult to
>   be embeded than Saiku in certain environment.
>
> On the other hand, as Pivot4J is designed to be UI independent API
>   from the start, it could provide more flexibility than Saiku in my
>   opinion to developers when they want to build their own application on
>   top of it, or intend to customize core behaviors of the API.
>
> For example, if you want to use Pivot4J with your own application
>   which is build with ExtJS, DhtmlX, or any other UI toolkits, it'd be
>   much easier to achieve a seamless integration with Pivot4J, as it
>   provides you with convenient abstract extension points to do that.
>
> Finally, if you're familiar with Javascript you might find working
>   with Saiku easier as it delegates most of the UI related works to the
>   client side.
>
> On the other hand, if you're an old school Java developer like me :)
>   you might find our sample application to be easier to understand and
>   work with, as there's virtually no custom script involved and
>   everything is done on the server side with JSF component model.
>
> To conclude, I'd like to say that Pivot4J is not just an API which
>   cannot be used without writing much codes as it already includes quite
>   feature complete Pentaho BI plugin for the upcoming 5.0 release of the
>   platform. And as Pivot4J and Saiku take rather different approach from
>   each other, each has its own strength and advantage which could be
>   leveraged to suit the specific use case.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15264827/1557981